# How do I get the current webpage name using php, when I'm also using the include function?

Tags: php, include

I have a simple webpage with a simple menu.

Each page of the webpage (for example, index.php, page-01.php etc) pulls the menu in using the include function:

```
<?php

include 'menu.php';

?>
```

I want the menu item for the current page formatted, so I'm trying to get the menu to check the name of the current page. For example, when I'm on index.php, I want a function in menu.php to return "index".

I tried using this in menu.php:

```
echo basename(__FILE__, '.php');
```

But it returns "menu" instead (which in retrospect, makes a lot of sense).

What can I use in my menu.php file to return the current page name?

Thanks!

Comment: Lookup `$_SERVER` variable. There are all infos you need.

Comment: Why do you have to know the page name **IN** menu.php? You can pass it to menu.php.

Comment: How about `pathinfo( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],PATHINFO_FILENAME );`?

Comment: Thanks shingo - in retrospect that was an obvious solution. And thanks @Professor Abronsius, that seems to be a much better way of getting the page name!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the path and query fragments of the URL as entered by user (`/blog/technology/latest?limit=10`), `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` to get the script file path relative to document root (`/blog/show-category.php`) and `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` to get the full path on server's disk (`/var/www/public/blog/show-category.php`). I think all these are pretty much standard across all server APIs, but it won't hurt to check in your server (run `phpinfo()` for a quick peek).

There's no general solution to map URLs to menu items since you can essentially code whatever structure you want. In the worst case, you'll have to store a map somewhere, maybe an array you also use to build the menu:

```
$routes = [
    'Latest posts' => [
        '/blog/lifestyle/latest' => 'Lifestyle',
        '/blog/technology/latest' => 'Technology',
    ],
];
```

If your project follows a legacy structure where individual scripts are just referenced in the URL, it should be straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function in the included file and call it with the current file name:

index.php, page-01.php, page-02.php...:

```
<?php
include 'menu.php';

$file = basename(__FILE__, '.php'); 
formatePage($file);
?>
```

menu.php:

```
<?php
function formatePage($file)
{
print $file;    
}
?>
```